# How to set SELECT LIMIT from user query string

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlite, query-string

Is it possible to set variable from URL query string value into SQLite3 LIMIT value? For example when user open endpoint /cities with query string ?per_page=10 the website return just 10 elements from cities.

When I put just limit_page variable after the LIMIT browser return `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: limit_page`

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    g,
    redirect,
    render_template,
    request,
    url_for,
    jsonify,

) import sqlite3, itertools

app = Flask(__name__)


DATABASE = 'database.db'


def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
        db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return db


@app.teardown_appcontext 
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.close()


@app.route('/cities') 
def city_list():
    limit_page = request.args.get('per_page')
    db = get_db()
    data = db.execute('''
    SELECT city FROM city LIMIT *limit_page*
    ''').fetchall()
    data_json = []
    for i in data:
        data_json.extend(list(i))

    return jsonify(data_json) 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a parameterised query:

```
limit_page = request.args.get('per_page')
if limit_page is not None:
    query = 'SELECT city FROM city LIMIT ?'
    args = (limit_page,)
else:
    query = 'SELECT city FROM city'
    args = ()
db = get_db()
data = db.execute(query, args).fetchall()
```

This will safely insert the value of `per_page` from the GET args into the SQL query and execute it. Using a parameterised query avoids common SQL injection attacks that would be otherwise present.